# How can i scan unknown number of inputs in c?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

How can I use for loop to scan unknown number of inputs in c using an array. I don't know what to put in the for loop

I tried this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int in[100];
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &in[i]);
        if (in[i] == -1) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also stop if the user tries to enter more elements than the array can hold.

Comment: `int array[ARRAY_LEN], i = 0; for (;;) { if (scanf("%d", array + i) != 1) break; i++; if (i == ARRAY_LEN) break; }`

Comment: How is your program supposed to know when the user has finished inputting numbers? Will the user be asked beforehand how many numbers he will be entering? Or should the user enter all numbers on a single line, so that your program knows that the user is finished when the user presses the ENTER key?

Comment: Will there be an upper limit on how many numbers are entered? For example, can you assume that the user will not enter more than 100 numbers?

Comment: StableCode, do you want to read until the user enters an <Enter>?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to tell when the input is done. You can either read *all* input until `stdin` is at `EOF` or let the user enter a specific value that means *"stop, I have no more input"*. It seems you've chosen `-1` to mean *"stop"*.

In your case, the loop should have been:

```
int i;   // declare i before the loop to be able to use it after the loop
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {   // note: check the boundary 100
    // check that scanf succeeds too:
    if(scanf(" %d", &in[i]) != 1 || in[i] == -1) {
        break;
    }
}
printf("you entered %d number of values\n", i);   // i used after the loop
```

You may also want to allocate the memory dynamically. Using an array of, say `int[100]`, will not be enough if the unknown amount turns out to be `101`.

Here's an example where the user is asked to enter any number of integers. Entering `-1` will exit the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    puts("Enter integers (-1 to stop): ");

    int *in = malloc(sizeof *in); // allocate space for 1 int
    unsigned count = 0;

    while(scanf(" %d", &in[count])==1 && in[count] != -1) {
        ++count;
        // allocate space for one more int:
        int *np = realloc(in, (count + 1) * sizeof *np);
        if(np == NULL) {
            puts("Can't allocate more memory. What you entered so far will have to do");
            break;
        }
        in = np;
    }

    printf("you entered %d number of values\n", count);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", in[i]);
    }

    free(in);
}
```